# react-native-fbsdk issues with pod FBSDKCoreKit

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to install the new version of react-native-fbsdk with the podfile instead of linking the libraries which does not work but I get this error message when doing pod install.

I use "react-native": "^0.59.5" and trying to make  "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.10.0", works.

```
Fetching podspec for `react-native-fbsdk` from `../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit":
  In Podfile:
    FBSDKCoreKit

    react-native-fbsdk (from `../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk`) was resolved to 0.10.0, which depends on
      react-native-fbsdk/Core (= 0.10.0) was resolved to 0.10.0, which depends on
        FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0.0)

Specs satisfying the `FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check minimum deployment target by:
"pod spec cat FBSDKCoreKit | grep -A 2 platform" then add minimum deployment target.

Comment: where do I add the minimum deployment target? It says 9.0 but this is already what I set it at in my Xcode project.